# Daylight Saving Time transition start time tests fail for 'GTB Standard Time' on Windows

Tags: .net, datetime, testing, timezone, dst

I wrote several tests for converting times from a specific timezone to UTC.

The rules say that in Europe the clocks are shifted forward at 01:00 UTC, for 'GTB Standard Time' this means +2 UTC, e.g. 03:00:00 .

However, I discovered that there are discrepancies in tests for different platforms (Linux vs Windows) using TimeZoneInfo.IsDaylightSavingTime(dateTime) method.

I created a new test object for DST transition date and time:

```
var testDate = new DateTime(2019, 03, 31, 03, 20, 00); //20 minutes after Daylight Saving Time start
...
```

And passed it in for TimeZoneInfo 'timeZone' object, where time zone was set to 'GTB Standard Time':

```
...
    var timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GTB Standard Time");
    return timeZone.IsDaylightSavingTime(testDate);
}
```

This returns **False**, although 03:20:00 locally on 2019-03-31 the daylight saving should already be ON. This should have returned True.

I managed to repeat this test only on Windows using built-in database for .Net timezones. With tzdata db (*NodaTime* for example) returns *True* for this test.

Confusing part was that 
I manually threw an error for the timeZone object to see what extra information comes from TimeZoneInfo object and found that DST start is actually correct:

```
timeZone.GetAdjustmentRules().First().DaylightTransitionStart.TimeOfDay
```

returns 03:00:00

Could someone confirm this and also is there a way to check where does windows take DST times? Can I make current test pass on both windows and linux without using any external libraries?

Comment: Could it be that `new DateTime(2019, 03, 31, 03, 20, 00)` returns a different UTC date based on your local time, so `testDate` isn't the same in both environments?

Comment: No, because I'm in the same time zone myself. The other environment is created on docker with mono image, where I set time zone the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The local time for this time zone goes from 02:59:59 to 04:00:00 on that particular day, thus 3:20:00 is invalid.  It falls into the gap created by the forward transition.

Per [the docs for `TimeZoneInfo.IsDaylightSavingTime(DateTime)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.isdaylightsavingtime#System_TimeZoneInfo_IsDaylightSavingTime_System_DateTime_)  (emphasis mine)

> If the dateTime parameter specifies an invalid time, the method call throws an ArgumentException if the value of the dateTime parameter's Kind property is DateTimeKind.Local; **otherwise, the method returns false.**

If you can, use `DateTimeOffset` types instead, or use `DateTime` with `DateTimeKind.Utc`.  With either, there is no possibility of invalid or ambiguous local time.

If you can't do that, then test your input values using `IsInvalidTime` and `IsAmbiguousTime` on the `TimeZoneInfo` object, then you can make a decision in your code about how you want to handle results.  For example, you may want to move 3:20 to 4:20 for that instance.

In the case of ambiguous time, be aware that all methods on `TimeZoneInfo` (`IsDaylightSavingTime`, `GetUtcOffset`, etc.) will assume the *standard time* by default, which comes second sequentially.  One almost always wants the daylight time in these scenarios.  You can get the two available offsets by calling `GetAmbiguousTimeOffsets` and choose the larger one.

Also, you mentioned Noda Time - A much better API, IMHO.   There, such things are handled by "resolvers" The default "lenient" resolver is used if you call `LocalDateTime.InZoneLeniently`.  There are other resolvers, and you can specify your own.  See the docs starting [here](https://nodatime.org/2.4.x/api/NodaTime.LocalDateTime.html#NodaTime_LocalDateTime_InZone_NodaTime_DateTimeZone_NodaTime_TimeZones_ZoneLocalMappingResolver_).